# Can I have a same test suite for Android and iOS mobile automation using Appium?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automation, appium, ui-automation, specflow

I am planning to automate cross platform app which is built in Typescript using Angular JS. UI of both Android and iOS will be exactly same. I am planning to automate the app.

Can I have a same test suite for android and iOS Mobile automation using Appium? Just for element identifier we have the two different file which we choose based on the device on which we have to execute?

In same project both Android and iOS can be automated? Is it possible?

I am using C# language for coding automation using appium. BDD framework (specflow).

Comment: Yes, it is possible<period>

Answer (score 2):

It is possible if you use page factory approach. We can have two different identifiers one for andriod and the other for IOS. Simple example below.

`@iOSFindBy(identifier = value)
@AndroidFindBy(identifier = value)
public MobileElement element`

Comment: Hi Vinay... But how to manage the driver statements..
for ios.. driver.findElementById("1").click(); (driver would be calling IWebElement
for android.. driver.findElementById("1").click(); (driver would be calling AndroidElement

Even if I write the driver instance in constructor then compile time error would pop since proect won't know which driver to use Android or IOS

Comment: I don''t have issues with identifiers since I am automating hybrid crosswalk app... and I have same identifiers for both

Comment: Hi Suraj, the identifier depends on type of driver object you pass to your identifier class. If you pass andriod driver then andriodfindby will be invoked and if you pass ios driver then iosfindby will be invoked.

Answer (score 0):

Check out Joyride: https://github.com/glorylo/Joyride, a cross platform mobile framework for automating acceptance tests using appium. It allows you to write the tests for both iOs and Android and share a lot of the code.

Good luck!

Comment: how to enable Webview for appium in C#
I tried using capabilities.SetCapability("autoWebView", "true");
but its giving `error: Invalid locator strategy: partial link text` Not able to identify any element after launch of cross platform app. App is developed in Ionic2